# How to increase the textarea of columns through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm retrieving data from a table through VBA.The select query gives output correctly.One of the columns that I select has text description which is multiline.So when I get my rows,I want to increase the textaread of my spreadsheet columns dynamically according to the results I'm getting.How can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **AutoFit** method on the columns containing your query result, for example

```
Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit ' hardcoded ... works but isn't nice
```

If you have a range defined for your query result, use this code fragment:

```
Dim QRslt As Range, QCol As Range

    '....
    For Each QCol In QRslt.Columns
        QCol.AutoFit
    Next
    '....
```

If you want to limit the column width to a certain maximum size you may as an alternative set the **.WrapText** property of the cells to **=True**

Hope that helps.

Good luck - MikeD

Comment: Wraptext was all that I needed